# Please add rounded corners for us WebKit users

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, user-interface, webkit

I think it's unfair that [Firefox users get rounded corners on their reputation / search bar.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29409/isaac-waller-997214-logout-about-faq-bar-has-no-rounded-corners) This is browserism. Us WebKit users (Android, iPhone, Chrome, Safari, etc.) should also get rounded corners. Please add [the required CSS](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29409/isaac-waller-997214-logout-about-faq-bar-has-no-rounded-corners/29411#29411):

```
-webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
-webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
```

Comment: Yeah, what he said!

Comment: Rounded corners are so... so... noughties!

Comment: Rounded corners! I like the utilitarian approach that exists. Very German.

Comment: `browserism` is definitely worth a new tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current CSS is:

```
#header #topbar
{
    width: auto;
    padding: 3px 10px 0px 10px;
    float: right;
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 22px;
    background-color: #eee;
    max-width: 750px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 3px;
    -webkit-border-radius-bottom-left: 3px;
    -webkit-border-radius-bottom-right: 3px;
}
```

Is that not correct? It's the same on all trilogy sites... I guess I can change it to your form.

Comment: I'm not getting rounded corners in Safari 4.0.4 (aka "the Not Found version").

Comment: you have -webkit-border-..."radius-bottom-left", he wants "bottom-left-radius". I'm guessing the difference is important.

Comment: I am getting them in Mobile Safari on Touch 3.1.2

Comment: I'm getting rounded corners now! Thank you!

Comment: you could go ahead and add the CSS 3.0 equivalents while you're at it. they are the same as the webkit specification, only without the `-webkit-`