# Stack Overflow 2.0?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, design

I've been using [this greasemonkey script](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/65674) for a while now and I love it (I love it so much that its the only thing keeping Google Chrome from becoming my default browser). It's called [StackOverflow 2.0](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/65674) and basically what it does is round the corners of certain objects, as well as a few other CSS tweaks, on the SO family of sites (see image below).

So I was just wondering if Jeff & company have ever thought about incorporating some of these features? Right now the only thing that I can see that is holding the script back is the use of the Firefox only `-moz-border-radius` property (however a few browsers now support the CSS3 `border-radius` property).

[image]

Comment: I like it. <!-- -->

Comment: Related, verging on duplicate: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35052/should-stackoverflow-com-have-rounded-corners and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35906/please-add-rounded-corners-for-us-webkit-users

Comment: Rounded corners are for pussies!

Comment: You are missing `font-size:1.5em` for everything as a base.

Comment: Greasemonkey is supported in the latest version of Chrome, so move over!

Comment: @Ivo: However every greasemonkey script I've tried to run doesn't want to work, with the exception of this one: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34836/

Comment: StackOverflow 2.0?  Huh, I'd call this "improvement" "StackOverflow 1.0.1".

Comment: More like "Stack Exchange 3.0" because we already have a "Stack Exchange 1.0"...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I'm going to make the corners *even sharper* now!

Comment: Hee. I don't really get the fixation with rounded corners.  Maybe I'm just strange.

Comment: It's all sharp corners on **Opera** 9.64

Comment: Ow!  Alright, where's the first aid kit...

Comment: @Jeff: My eyes have received enough paper cuts from these sharp edges! **I demand you round them now!**